# WordPress. Загрузка файла прервана из-за расширения

Tags: wordpress

Еще вчера все было хорошо, а сегодня вот такая проблема. Инернет ответа не дал. Плагины отключал, кеш и куки удалял. Все обновлено.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи, сами понимаете, без картинок сайт мертв

Comment: Буквально сегодня на оф форуме https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9/

Comment: @SeVlad это оооочень странно, но, просто пересохранив файлы(png и jpg), смог загрузить без проблем.

Comment: Да странно.. Но вряд ли виноват ВП. Не скажешь, какой хостинг, версия php и IMagick? Плагины типа ватермарков или др для изменения графики используются? Какие?

Comment: @SeVlad. Не знаю, гле глянуть imagick. Хостинг ihc.ru, php 7.1.12. Графика никак не изменется, только Smush,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта проблема связана с версией PHP. Просто поменяй её, или откати обновление. Это инфа от хостера ihc, их решение мне помогло.